# How to constrain my LSTM model to make it has positive derivative of in put?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Hope you are doing great and I was wondering if anyone could give some suggestions.
To make it simple,let us consider an "seq to 1" example: y=LSTM(x). x has sequence length of 10, with 3 features. y has 1 feature.

If I know exactly with the increase of the 2nd feature x[:,2], y should increase as well. Which means, logically, the derivative: dy/dx[:,2] > 0.

Then my question is, how to add this constrain into my NN, I am using Pytorch.
I know how to do it for ANN, but LSTM/GRU has Hadamard product, which makes this problem super tricky... Especially x is a sequence, it could go through lots of gate unit...

Luckily, the sigmoid and tanh is friendly for derivative, and the output of gate is always within (-1,1) or (0,1). So I tried to "weakly" proof, under "some" conditions, if I force "some" parameters in a "certain" range, then the LSTM can give me correct response. But so far, I couldn't find a well constructed way to do it...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.